# Is there a rake command to reset a Redmine admin password?

Tags: redmine, reset, forgot-password

I have lost the admin password for a `redmine` installation, and after trying the method of clearing the salt and setting the default hash for the password `password` I still cannot login.

Is there a rake command to set the default password, or set a specific password?

The `Redmine` version is 2.4.2

Comment: Not sure (I don't have installed Redmine now so I can't check) but I believe you can do it through `rails c`. You can load `RAILS_ENV=production rails c` then something like this: `u = User.where(email: 'your_email@gmail.com').first; u.password = '123123'; u.password_confirmation = '123123'; u.save!`

Comment: Can you provide me with the exact syntax? Working with Rails on the command line is something I have no knowledge of. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you can reset your (any) password from rails console. Go to the Redmine folder on server and

```
# start console
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c

# find your user
user = User.where(email: 'your_email@gmail.com').first

# set new password
user.password = '123123'
user.password_confirmation = '123123'

# save changes
user.save!
```

Please note if `save!` returns exception then changes can not be applied. Post exception message to the question.

Comment: That's true and worked for me, but  'cd $REDMINE_ROOT' is needed before, for starting console successfully.

Comment: `bundle exec rails c -e production` is better for login in production environment

Answer (score 4):

If you don't remember the admin email address, another option is to use the userid .

1. get your admin user id.

   mysql -u redmine_user -p    # login MySQL

   mysql> use redmine;         # choose redmine database

   mysql> select id,login from users where login='admin';  # show admin info

Now you have your admin id (first column) it should be 1 but can be any number if you have delete and recreated your admin user.

2. Go to the redmine folder and change the password

   su - redmine_user               # go under redmine user if you have one

   cd /var/www/redmine             # cd in redmine document root

   # start the console

   RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c

Wait until rail env come up.

```
# Load your admin user, I use id = 1 here but it should be what you have found in step 1 
user = User.where(id: 1).first

# set new password
user.password = 'password'
user.password_confirmation = 'password'

# save changes
user.save!
exit
```

Your done !

Bye

Comment: The answer at zlargon.github.io is copied from the accepted answer to this one. You response is better changed to a comment describing a general way to get a key to the required user id.

Comment: 'select * from users' returns too many columns. You'd better limit the columns returned